# Run python-rq worker process on application start

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-rq

I hosted my Django app on Heroku but due to few limitations I moved from Heroku to cloud based server. I followed this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) on running background tasks in Python. Everything is running fine except that I have to manually run `python worker.py` to start worker process.

On Heroku we can use Procfile to run processes when app starts but now I am on a cloud based server running ubuntu 14.04. So what is the alternative to Procfile?

**worker.py**

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Connection(conn):
       worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
       worker.work()
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using upstart. I created a new config file `rqworker.py` using `sudo nano \etc\init\rqworker.conf` with the following code:

```
description "Job queues for directory"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuser
setgid www-data

exec python3.5 worker.py
```

Then I just started the service `sudo service rqworker start` and now my worker processes are running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Use a process manager like upstart, systemd or supervisor.

Comment: Thanks! I did end up using upstart.